# php exec not working with vars

Tags: php, exec

I have been using an exec command  to pass variables and execute a mailer script.  For some reason it has stopped working.

Here's the command line

```
exec("$path_to_php $emailer $digest_sub_security_var \"$vid_menu\" \"$image_menu\" \"$article_menu\" $media_query_lmt_v $media_query_lmt_i $media_query_lmt_a > /dev/null &");
```

When I started experimenting by removing some of the vars like this

```
exec("$path_to_php $emailer $digest_sub_security_var \"$vid_menu\" > /dev/null &");
```

It started working again.  How can I add the other variables and get it working again?

Comment: [see the documentation](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) for escaping arguments for shell commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably in the value of some of vars. You probably made some change in your program and inadvertently changed some of those values.

Simply print the string you're sending to exec (instead of executing it) or construct a string with all the variables:

```
print("path_to_php = $path_to_php ### emailer = $emailer ### digest_sub_security_var = $digest_sub_security_var ... ");
```

Look at the resulting output. That should give you an idea of what variable changed and where you need to fix your code.

If this does not help copy the string being executed and run it on a shell (without the `"> /dev/null &"` at the end). Hopefully the script will provide some useful error.

Comment: Thankyou.  I think you were right. I changed the command line as follows exec("$path_to_php $emailer $digest_sub_security_var '$vid_menu' '$image_menu' '$article_menu' $media_query_lmt_v $media_query_lmt_i $media_query_lmt_a > /dev/null &");  This seems to have fixed it., although Im not entirely sure why.